# How to get back the classic statusbar in Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox, statusbar

I recently installed Firefox 4b7, under Windows and 4b8 under Ubuntu at home. In both cases, I miss the status bar in the bottom of the window. Some of the add-ons that I use, such as XMarks, are using it to display some icons, as well as accessing some other functions.

How can I restore this statusbar under Firefox 4 ?

Merci !

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on one of the toolbars and select "Add-on Bar". You can also select it from under the Firefox Menu under the "Options" sub-menu.

[image: Screenshot of the Options sub-menu where you can find the Add-on Bar option]

Also, if you're wanting to get back the classic status bar functions such as displaying the page loading status, you can install the [Status-4-Evar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/235283/) add-on.